# How to search for email of a particular date from years ago in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

There are similar questions and several answers. I tried to follow the methods provided in the answers.  They did not work. So I am going to ask it again with more specifics.

I only knew the date of the email in the in-box in 2012 and the content of it but did not know the exact wording of the subject. Is it possible to find this email?

Answer (score 3):

**Try the `before:{date}` and `after:{date}` search operators.**, in addition to any search terms or sender filters you can remember. This can be done by typing them into the search bar, or by dropping down the search options and searching by date, e.g. `within 2 weeks of {date}`.

```
before:2012/12/31 after:2012/1/1 search terms
```

There is no `between` filter - see the [entire Gmail search operator list](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190).

Comment: If you know the specific date, I'd include the day before and the day after, just in case: `after:2012/3/2 before:2012/3/4` for March 3.